# Nested objects in Windows Forms property grid view and browsable attribute

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

So in .NET 6. Windows Forms, I create simple form with property grid, and very simple object:

```
public class MainObject
{
    [Category("Main object")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Main object name";
 
    [Category("Main object")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DisplayName("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; } = "Main object value";
 
    [Category("Main object")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DisplayName("Nested object")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(NestedObjectTypeConverter))]
    public NestedObject NestedObject { get; set; } = new();
 
}
```

Here is TypeConverter

```
public class NestedObjectTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
    {
        return true;
    }
 
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, object? value, Attribute[]? attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(NestedObject));
    }
}
```

And here is nested object

```
public class NestedObject
{
    [Category("Nested object")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Nested name";
 
    [Category("Nested object")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DisplayName("Visible value")]
    public string VisibleValue { get; set; } = "Visible value. Browsable set to \"true\" and it show.";
 
    [Category("Nested object")]
    //This is key point
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DisplayName("Invisible value")]
    public string InvisibleValue { get; set; } = "Invisible value. Browsable set to \"false\" but it still show.";
 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Nested object (expand me please)";
    }
}
```

In property grid this object shows fine. But "Browsable" attribute for field InvisibleValue completely ignored. This field always displayed. This attribute not exist in object fields list and so on.

I'm trying to set "Browsable" with standard reflection but without success, because unable to get "browsable" attribute from type descriptor and attribute. This attribute always "null".

Comment: You're ignoring the Properties' attributes in your TypeConverter, change in `return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(NestedObject), attributes);` -- Also, consider what the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` should be set to in your hidden property (also EditorBrowsable, eventually, I don't really know the use case of these classes)

Comment: You may want to also consider `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` in the class as well as the reflector.